# Using mediaplayer in adapter of gridview

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer, android-gridview

I am playing audios in a gridview.I am having  two issues

1.once the audio starts it not pausing or stopping.On clicking on pause button I see the pause image changing to play but still the audio keeps playing.If i click on another item's play button then multiple audio plays.I failed to understand why  `mp.pause()` not working

2.its playing wrong audio when clicking on an item..it plays some other item's audio

Answer (score 0):

MediaPlayer should be static and initialized in adapter's constructor and the file should be declared final.